# Automating password fails when using lftp -u username, passwd

Tags: passwords, sftp, lftp

My question is when using lftp to download file from a sftp site with automating password :

```
lftp -e 'set xfer:clobber on; mget -c one_file' -u username,passwd  sftp://hostname
```

lftp still prompt "Enter your PASSWORD:" to ask me the password. My operating system is Windows xp. Can anybody tell me what is problem ?

Background:
I want to transfer large files automatically from a sftp site when some condition is met. I find lftp is a good tool to transfer large files because it can resume the transfer in background when the link is disconnected due to the instable net connect status. I use python on Windows to control lftp to download the large files. But it seems to automating password in lftp is failed. I also try the expect-like method, such as winpexpect, but it seems can't solve this problem. However, I find others use lftp -u to automate password for sftp site when doing google searching, why it failed here ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> I have solved it.
>
> I find the `ssh` used by `lftp` is not the one in the directory of `lftp`, but another one (`ssh` under the directory of `mingw`) because the route of `mingw` in `PATH` is prior to `lftp`. I move the route of `lftp` in front of `mingw` in `PATH` variable, then the problem is solved.